# Compare list to ElementCollection in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data

I am trying to compare a list of elements to a @ElementCollection field of an entity to ensure they contain exactly the same elements, but I'm having a bit of trouble. A simplified code example probably better illustrates the problem:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ExampleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> tokens;
}
```

Given the above entity, I would expect to be able to have a query which can take in a List and compare to 'tokens' to find ExampleEntities which have exactly the same tokens (and also importantly, in the same order), however the below repository does not work:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ExampleEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<ExampleEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM ExampleEntity e WHERE e.tokens = :tokens")
    public ExampleEntity findEntitiesMatchingTokens(@Param("tokens") List<String> tokens);

}
```

The relevant part of the stack trace is:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not prepare statement; SQL [select exampleent0_.id as id1_2_ from
>   example_entity exampleent0_ cross join example_entity_tokens tokens1_
>   where exampleent0_.id=tokens1_.example_entity_id and .=(? , ? , ?)];
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
>   not prepare statement] with root cause
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT
>   EXAMPLEENT0_.ID AS ID1_2_ FROM EXAMPLE_ENTITY EXAMPLEENT0_ CROSS JOIN
>   EXAMPLE_ENTITY_TOKENS TOKENS1_ WHERE
>   EXAMPLEENT0_.ID=TOKENS1_.EXAMPLE_ENTITY_ID AND .[*]=(? , ? , ?) ";
>   expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM, WITH"; SQL statement:
>   select exampleent0_.id as id1_2_ from example_entity exampleent0_
>   cross join example_entity_tokens tokens1_ where
>   exampleent0_.id=tokens1_.example_entity_id and .=(? , ? , ?)
>   [42001-196]

So it looks like you cannot try to compare lists in this way. Is there any neat way to do this with a @Query in Spring Data?

Thanks in advance!